# Form submit event is not dispatched correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on a piece of code made with react-bootstrap, include FormControl and InputGroup. The thing looks like:

```
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Container
      fluid={true}
      className={[styles.container, 'justify-content-start flex-column'].join(
        ' '
      )}
    >
      <Form
        onSubmit={e => console.log('submitting:', e)}
        className={styles.searchForm}
        ref={formRef}
      >
        <div className={styles.searchInput}>
          <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
            <InputGroup className={styles.inputGroup}>
              <FormControl
                placeholder='Locality'
                aria-label='Search locality'
              />
              <InputGroup.Append>
                <Icon
                  icon={faMapMarker}
                  classes={styles.searchInputOpaqueIcon}
                  onClick={async () => {
                    try {
                      const position = await getPosition();
                      setPosition(position);
                    } catch (err) {
                      console.error(err.message);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </InputGroup.Append>
            </InputGroup>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
            <InputGroup>
              <FormControl placeholder='Search...' aria-label='Search string' />
              <InputGroup.Append>
                <Icon
                  icon={faSearch}
                  classes={styles.searchInputIcon}
                  onClick={() => {
                    formRef.current.dispatchEvent(
                      new Event('submit', { cancelable: true })
                    );
                    console.log('dispatched submit');
                  }}
                />
              </InputGroup.Append>
            </InputGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Icon onClick={close} icon={faTimesCircle} classes={styles.closeIcon} />
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
```

I was under the impression that dispatching the submit event, like above, should trigger form submission and therefore `onSubmit`. This is not happening. I see from the console log that dispatch went through and onSubmit is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
            <Icon
              icon={faSearch}
              classes={styles.searchInputIcon}
              onClick={() => {
                if (typeof formRef.current.requestSubmit === 'function') {
                  formRef.current.requestSubmit();
                  console.log('requested submit');
                } else {
                  formRef.current.dispatchEvent(
                    new Event('submit', { cancelable: true })
                  );
                  console.log('dispatched submit');
                }
              }}
            />
```